# List comprehension & ternary operator -> SyntaxError

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

With `text`, `type`, `scope` being string and `val`, `altval` being int, why is the following code syntatically not correct? (I know this isn't the correct way to do it aesthatically but would that affect syntax?)

```
result = [(i[val:] if scope=="before" else i[:val] if scope=="after" else i[val:altval] if scope=="beforeafter" else i) if j<=until for j,i in enumerate(text.split("\n"))]
```

Broken down into lines:

```
result = [ 
(i[val:] if scope=="before"
else i[:val] if scope=="after"
else i[val:altval] if scope=="beforeafter"
else i) if j<=until
for j,i in enumerate(text.split("\n"))]
```

With lines split up as this, the `SyntaxError` is at the last line:

```
for j,i in enumerate(text.split("\n"))]
^
```

Version: Python 3.x
System: Windows

What am I missing? Is it a list comprehension limitation?

Comment: You have no `else` to go with `if j < until`

Comment: If that's supposed to be a filter rather than a ternary, it should be after `for j, i in enumerate(text.split("\n"))`

Comment: And if you only want to process the first `until+1` elements, you can do that by slicing the result of `text.split()` instead of using `enumerate()`

Comment: `text.split("\n")[:until+1]`

Comment: Thanks, adding else seems to be working. 
(edit: just tried and using `text.split("\n")[:until+1]` does the job, but still, in general) Is there a way I can express "append nothing" in `else`? @Barmar --

Comment: You do that by using a filter instead of a ternary.

Comment: BTW, that not a "ternary operator". It's a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (and always has an `else`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move the last `if` condition after `for`:

```py
result = [
   (
    i[val:] if scope=="before"
    else i[:val] if scope=="after"
    else i[val:altval] if scope=="beforeafter"
    else i
   ) for j, i in enumerate(text.split("\n"))
   if j <= until
]
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6k3xT31)</kbd>

Comment: would this continue the for loop if the case in "if" is True or start the for loop if the case in "if" is True?

Comment: The loop runs but returns values only by that filtered logic.